# Memory leaking while declaring viewBinding

Tags: android

I declare viewBinding outside of the MainActivity class like this:

`private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding`

but I'm getting a warning:

`` Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static reference to `ActivityMainBinding` which has field `tvTasksTitle` pointing to `TextView`); this is a memory leak ``

I always declared viewBinding like this in previous projects and didn't get any warnings. Of course, I can continue the project, but I would like to know the reason why. I searched the internet but couldn't find a proper answer or a workaround.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it inside the MainActivity, not outside.  If it's outside, it will last beyond the Activity, which will create a memory leak (not might, it 100% will).  Also, this will cause all instances of an Activity to share the same binding.  This is a bug-  its possible (in fact expected) for multiple copies of an Activity to exist, and this can cause old instances of the Activity to reference the binding for a newer instance, which can cause incorrect behavior and race conditions.

The solution is just to make it a variable inside of the MainActivity class, so it's a property of the instance.

Comment: thank you for your answer! but almost every tutorial about viewbinding, even official android developers website declares it outside the class. why is that so? mentioned website: [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities)

Comment: No they don't.  Look at the code on that page-  it's above the onCreate function.  It's still inside the class.

Comment: oops, my mistake. I got it. thank you for your time)